# Equating terms of a summation

Tags: summation

Suppose I have an equation of summations in the form:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kz^k=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}b_kz^k$$

Under what conditions and how can I deduce that: $$a_k=b_k\  \forall k$$

Thank you in advance for your answer

Comment: Always, as long as the equality holds for every $z$ in an interval $]-R,R[$, with $R>0$.

Comment: It's called  the identity theorem for complex power series. There is a maximal radius $r$ such that for all $|z|<r$ the series converges absolutely. Inside the  common circle of convergency sums can be combined termwise and $0(z) = \sum (a_k-b_k)z^k  $ is the zero function with $r=\infty$.

Comment: The corresp. coeffs are equal for all $k \in \Bbb{N}$ if you deal in __formal__ power series.

Comment: the set $\{z^k\}_k$ forms a basis within the function space - in fact this is the idea behind the Taylor series of a function